# Show that the following vector is perpendicular to $L_1$

Tags: vectors

A textbook question reads,

The line $L_1$ has vector equation  $ r = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -3 \\ -3 \\\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ 2 \\\end{bmatrix}$.

Another line is perpendicular to $L_1$ and is represented by $r= \begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 11 \\ 7 \\\end{bmatrix} + g\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ 1 \\\end{bmatrix} $.

Show that $x = -3$.

Isn't this an error? Does not x need to equal -1 to have the lines perpendicular (dot product)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're right. $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -3 \\ -3 \\\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 11 \\ 7 \\\end{bmatrix}$ shouldn't affect the calculation of orthogonality, since the same lines can be parameterized using any vectors whose end points lie somewhere along the lines.

So we can be certain that we're only concerned with $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 3 \\ 2 \\\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ x \\ 1 \\\end{bmatrix}$. And you're correct; the dot product of those two vectors is $1*1+3x+2*1=3x+3$, which should equal $0$ if the lines are to be perpendicular, and that's only true when $x=-1$.